# ARkit Xamarin - How to position the origin of the world in the place of a detected image?

Tags: xamarin.ios, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I'm developing an augmented reality app using Xamarin with ARKit.

My goal is that after recognizing an image by the camera, the app can position the origin of the world right on top of the QRCode for example.

The problem is that in my ARSCNViewDelegate method "DidAddNode" it returns the Anchor of the camera position and not the recognized image. I understand that the point where he identified the image is in the SCNNode but I can't find any property to assign in the "setWorldOrigin" method

I already managed to place a 3D object directly in the QR Code, but I would like to assign the origin of the world in the QRCode and place the 3D object by coordinates. Follow my code below and what I've already tried:

```
using ARKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using OpenTK;
using SceneKit;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UIKit;

namespace MyAppARKit
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        private ARSCNView sceneView;

        public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            this.sceneView = new ARSCNView() {
                AutoenablesDefaultLighting = true,
                DebugOptions = ARSCNDebugOptions.ShowWorldOrigin,
                //DebugOptions = ARSCNDebugOptions.ShowFeaturePoints | ARSCNDebugOptions.ShowWorldOrigin,
                //Delegate = new SceneViewDelegate(this.sceneView)
            };

            this.sceneView.Delegate = new SceneViewDelegate(this.sceneView);

            this.View.AddSubview(this.sceneView);
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            this.sceneView.Frame = this.View.Frame;
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

            var detectionImages = ARReferenceImage.GetReferenceImagesInGroup("AR Resources", null);

            this.sceneView.Session.Run(new ARWorldTrackingConfiguration
            {
                AutoFocusEnabled = true,
                PlaneDetection = ARPlaneDetection.Horizontal | ARPlaneDetection.Vertical,
                LightEstimationEnabled = true,
                WorldAlignment = ARWorldAlignment.GravityAndHeading,
                FrameSemantics = ARFrameSemantics.PersonSegmentationWithDepth,
                DetectionImages = detectionImages,
                MaximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 3,
                
            }, ARSessionRunOptions.ResetTracking | ARSessionRunOptions.RemoveExistingAnchors);
        }

        public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);

            //this.sceneView.Session.Pause();
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }
    }

    public class SessionDelegate : ARSessionDelegate
    {
        public SessionDelegate() { }

        public override void CameraDidChangeTrackingState(ARSession session, ARCamera camera)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", camera.TrackingState, camera.TrackingStateReason);
        }
    }

    public class SceneViewDelegate : ARSCNViewDelegate
    {
        private ARSCNView _sceneView;
        private ARAnchor currentAnchor;

        public SceneViewDelegate(ARSCNView sceneView)
        {
            _sceneView = sceneView;
        }

        public override void DidAddNode(ISCNSceneRenderer renderer, SCNNode node, ARAnchor anchor)
        {
            currentAnchor = anchor;

            if (anchor is ARImageAnchor imageAnchor)
            {
                var detectedImage = imageAnchor.ReferenceImage;

                node.AddChildNode(CreateModelNodeFromFile("files/wood.dae", "Wood_Table"));

                _sceneView.Session.SetWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: anchor.Transform);
                _sceneView.Scene.RootNode.AddChildNode(CreateModelNodeFromFile("files/plant.dae", "Low-Poly_Plant_"));

                node.AddChildNode(CreateModelNodeFromFile("files/wood.dae", "Wood_Table"));
            }
        }

        private Vector3 ExtractTranslation(NMatrix4 matrix)
        {
            return new Vector3(matrix.Column3.X, matrix.Column3.Y, matrix.Column3.Z);
        }

        public static float ConvertDegreesToRadians(float angle)
        {
            return (float)(Math.PI / 180) * angle;
        }

        public static SCNNode CreateModelNodeFromFile(string filePath, string rootNodeName)
        {
            var sceneFromFile = SCNScene.FromFile(filePath);

            var model = sceneFromFile.RootNode.FindChildNode(rootNodeName, true);

            model.Scale = new SCNVector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
            model.Position = new SCNVector3(0, 0, 0);
            float angle = (float)(-Math.PI / 2);
            model.EulerAngles = new SCNVector3(angle, angle, 0);

            // Animate the opacity to 100% over 0.75 seconds
            //model.RunAction(SCNAction.FadeIn(1));

            return model;
        }

        public override void DidRemoveNode(ISCNSceneRenderer renderer, SCNNode node, ARAnchor anchor)
        {
            if (anchor is ARPlaneAnchor planeAnchor)
            {
            }
        }

        public override void DidUpdateNode(ISCNSceneRenderer renderer, SCNNode node, ARAnchor anchor)
        {
            if (anchor is ARPlaneAnchor planeAnchor)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```